# Microstrain 3DM-GX3-45 with imu_drivers

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I have Microstrain 3DM-GX3-45, and testing with imu_drivers stack.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu

However, the error message below shown. Have anyone suffered similar problem?

[ERROR] [1343116268.721230462]: Exception thrown while starting IMU. This sometimes happens if you are not connected to an IMU or if another process is trying to access the IMU port. You may try 'lsof|grep /dev/ttyUSB1' to see if other processes have the port open. invalid checksum.
Make sure the IMU sensor is connected to this computer. (in microstrain_3dmgx2_imu::IMU:receive) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Troubleshooting

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39600/microstrain-3dm-gx3-45-with-imu_drivers/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-07-23**:
I'm sure that there is no other process using ttyUSB1

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-27**:
Do you receive any errors in your /var/log/messages when plugging it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The data communications protocol for the various MicroStrain 3DM inertial sensors is different. The 3DM-GX2, 3DM-GX3-25 and 3DM-GX3-35/45 each have a separate data communications protocol. All of these can be found at: http://www.microstrain.com/inertial/sensors. The error certainly could mean that the communication cable and/or power is disconnected/broken/mis-wired/etc. A number of other reasons could also cause the error including 1) the command being sent is not the correct command for the particular inertial sensor, 2) the serial port is not set correctly, 3) the command being sent is not structured correctly, 4) the sensor is busy with a previously instructed command, 5) the sensor is damaged, and so forth. A terminal program is often useful to observe the actual TX and RX traffic and troubleshoot the problem.

---

Originally posted by [MicroStrain Support](https://answers.ros.org/users/2933/microstrain-support/) with karma: 76 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1